# changing the text while selecting an item in list view using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

im using visual studio 2012 and ms access as my database...

this is my form

```
Private Sub formCustomerList_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.lvwCustomer.Columns.Add("Family Name", 130)
    Me.lvwCustomer.Columns.Add("Given Name", 140)
    Me.lvwCustomer.Columns.Add("Middle Initial", 80)
    Me.lvwCustomer.Columns.Add("Contact Number", 110)
    Me.lvwCustomer.Columns.Add("Address", 200)
```

i have a "label" called idLabel and nameLabel
now my problem is, my idLabel doesn't change the txt value into the equivalent id to the selected index in my listview... is it possible to output the id if there is no column "id" in the listview?

thanks in advance

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could construct a small but complete example that shows your problem.

Comment: i have 2 labels which are idLabel and nameLabel..
i have 1 listview called lvwCustomerList

in my database... i have customerID=cust1234, familyName=price, givenName=john, middleInitial=s., contactNumber=1234, address=qwerty

but in my listview it doesn't have the customerID as you can see in my code above...

if i select john in the listview... the idLabel.text whill change into customer1234 which is the customerID..

Comment: A listview is very ill suited to DB ops.  A DataGridView would work much better and - believe it or not - be easier using a DataSource

Comment: Based on what you are doing you should use a datatable with a datagridview. This should also help when pulling and pushing data between .net and access